# VBA Excel macro to set value from pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, ssas

I have pivot table on excel,
where data source come from SSAS SQL,

i want to set automatic the date as date using macro VBA,
so when i hit a button the asofdate will change D-1  and retrive the data

[image]

i cant find the solution to use macro to set this date pivot

Comment: Honestly, I did not understand your query....